# Need help filtering nested json object recursively

Tags: javascript, json, algorithm, dictionary, recursion

I have a JSON object "data" in React that has other objects nested inside it, think of it as a **directory/ file structure** where the number of layers is arbitrary.

```
const data = {
        "item1": {
            "item1.1": {
                "item1.1.1": {
                    "item1.1.1.1": {
                        "attr1": [],
                        "attr2": "",
                        "attr3": [],
                        "status" : "ERROR"
                    }
                }
            },
            "item1.2": {
                "item1.2.1": {
                    "item1.2.1.1": {
                        "attr1": [],
                        "attr2": "",
                        "attr3": [],
                        "status" : "WARNING"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "item2": {
            "item2.1": {
                "item2.1.1": {
                    "item2.1.1.1": {
                        "attr1": [],
                        "attr2": "",
                        "attr3": [],
                        "status" : "WARNING"
                    }
                },
                "item2.1.2": {
                    "item2.1.2.1": {
                        "attr1": [],
                        "attr2": "",
                        "attr3": [],
                        "status" : "OK"
                    },
                    "item2.1.2.2": {
                        "attr1": [],
                        "attr2": "",
                        "attr3": [],
                        "status" : "WARNING"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "item3": {
            "item3.1": {
                "item3.1.1": {
                    "item3.1.1.1": {
                        "attr1": [],
                        "attr2": "",
                        "attr3": [],
                        "status" : "OK"
                    }
                },
                "item3.1.2": {
                    "attr1": [],
                    "attr2": "",
                    "attr3": [],
                    "status" : "ERROR"
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

**I'm trying to write a function that would filter the object based on the status value.**

for example, getStatuses(data, "ERROR") will return a list of all the objects with the status being "ERROR". The expected return value is:

```
{"item1.1.1.1": {"attr1": [], "attr2": "", "attr3": [], "status" : "ERROR"},
 "item3.1.2": {"attr1": [],"attr2": "", "attr3": [], "status" : "ERROR"}
}
```

My thoughts are that the function needs to loop through the data recursively and then push the matching objects into a list, but my logic seems to be flawed as I am not getting the right results.

```
    const getStatuses= (obj, status) => {
        let result = [];
        if (obj.status === status) {
            result.push(obj)
        }

        Object.entries(obj).forEach(([, value]) => {
            //if object is not a leaf node
            if (value !== null && !Array.isArray(value) && typeof value === 'object') {
                getStatuses(value, status); //recursive call to dive in another layer
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: "I am not getting the right results": can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adapting the lovely function `iterate` we can easily iterate a tree. On the way we collect all those with the searched status.

This solution is the same as the others. Only easier to find.

```js
const data={item1:{"item1.1":{"item1.1.1":{"item1.1.1.1":{attr1:[],attr2:"",attr3:[],status:"ERROR"}}},"item1.2":{"item1.2.1":{"item1.2.1.1":{attr1:[],attr2:"",attr3:[],status:"WARNING"}}}},item2:{"item2.1":{"item2.1.1":{"item2.1.1.1":{attr1:[],attr2:"",attr3:[],status:"WARNING"}},"item2.1.2":{"item2.1.2.1":{attr1:[],attr2:"",attr3:[],status:"OK"},"item2.1.2.2":{attr1:[],attr2:"",attr3:[],status:"WARNING"}}}},item3:{"item3.1":{"item3.1.1":{"item3.1.1.1":{attr1:[],attr2:"",attr3:[],status:"OK"}},"item3.1.2":{attr1:[],attr2:"",attr3:[],status:"ERROR"}}}};

function getStatuses(data, status) {

  var result = {}
  
  const iterate = (obj) => {
    if (!obj) {
      return;
    }
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
      var value = obj[key]
      if (typeof value === "object" && value !== null) {
        iterate(value)
        if (value.status == status) {
          result[key] = value;
        } 
      }
    })
  }

  iterate(data)
  return result;
}
console.log (getStatuses(data,"ERROR"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function doesn't return anything: the `push` happens on a local variable that is lost, and the pushed object is not associated with a key.

I would suggest a recursive generator that returns pairs of keys and associated objects. The caller can then assemble these into an object using `Object.fromEntries`:

```js
function* iterMatches(data, status) {
    if (Object(data) !== data) return; // A primitive
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
        if (value?.status === status) yield [key, value];
        yield* iterMatches(value, status);
    }
}

const data = {"item1": {"item1.1": {"item1.1.1": {"item1.1.1.1": {"attr1": [],"attr2": "","attr3": [],"status" : "ERROR"}}},"item1.2": {"item1.2.1": {"item1.2.1.1": {"attr1": [],"attr2": "","attr3": [],"status" : "WARNING"}}}},"item2": {"item2.1": {"item2.1.1": {"item2.1.1.1": {"attr1": [],"attr2": "","attr3": [],"status" : "WARNING"}},"item2.1.2": {"item2.1.2.1": {"attr1": [],"attr2": "","attr3": [],"status" : "OK"},"item2.1.2.2": {"attr1": [],"attr2": "","attr3": [],"status" : "WARNING"}}}},"item3": {"item3.1": {"item3.1.1": {"item3.1.1.1": {"attr1": [],"attr2": "","attr3": [],"status" : "OK"}},"item3.1.2": {"attr1": [],"attr2": "","attr3": [],"status" : "ERROR"}}}};
console.log(Object.fromEntries(iterMatches(data, "ERROR")));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to save not only the values (the objects with the matching `status`) but also the keys, so pushing to an array won't work. You also need a persistent output structure (don't re-create it anew each time the function runs). This can be done with a default argument that gets passed along each recursive call. In each call, loop over both the keys and the values of each child property, and if a value fulfills the condition, assign the key and value to the output.

```js
const data={item1:{"item1.1":{"item1.1.1":{"item1.1.1.1":{attr1:[],attr2:"",attr3:[],status:"ERROR"}}},"item1.2":{"item1.2.1":{"item1.2.1.1":{attr1:[],attr2:"",attr3:[],status:"WARNING"}}}},item2:{"item2.1":{"item2.1.1":{"item2.1.1.1":{attr1:[],attr2:"",attr3:[],status:"WARNING"}},"item2.1.2":{"item2.1.2.1":{attr1:[],attr2:"",attr3:[],status:"OK"},"item2.1.2.2":{attr1:[],attr2:"",attr3:[],status:"WARNING"}}}},item3:{"item3.1":{"item3.1.1":{"item3.1.1.1":{attr1:[],attr2:"",attr3:[],status:"OK"}},"item3.1.2":{attr1:[],attr2:"",attr3:[],status:"ERROR"}}}};

const getStatuses = (inputObj, status, outputObj = {}) => {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(inputObj)) {
    if (value.status === status) {
      outputObj[key] = value;
    } else if (typeof value === 'object' && !Array.isArray(value)) {
      getStatuses(value, status, outputObj);
    }
  }
  return outputObj;
}
console.log(getStatuses(data, 'ERROR'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You already got 2 really good answers that followed how you were solving the problem so I just want to add something that it's kinda different.

If in your case the performance isn't a big factor, you could get much more readable and reusable code by separating the problem in 2 parts, which would be  (1) flatten the object, and then (2) filtering the objects with the status you want.

You can see an example of what I explained below:

```js
const data = {
    "item1": {
        "item1.1": {
            "item1.1.1": {
                "item1.1.1.1": {
                    "attr1": [],
                    "attr2": "",
                    "attr3": [],
                    "status" : "ERROR"
                }
            }
        },
        "item1.2": {
            "item1.2.1": {
                "item1.2.1.1": {
                    "attr1": [],
                    "attr2": "",
                    "attr3": [],
                    "status" : "WARNING"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "item2": {
        "item2.1": {
            "item2.1.1": {
                "item2.1.1.1": {
                    "attr1": [],
                    "attr2": "",
                    "attr3": [],
                    "status" : "WARNING"
                }
            },
            "item2.1.2": {
                "item2.1.2.1": {
                    "attr1": [],
                    "attr2": "",
                    "attr3": [],
                    "status" : "OK"
                },
                "item2.1.2.2": {
                    "attr1": [],
                    "attr2": "",
                    "attr3": [],
                    "status" : "WARNING"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "item3": {
        "item3.1": {
            "item3.1.1": {
                "item3.1.1.1": {
                    "attr1": [],
                    "attr2": "",
                    "attr3": [],
                    "status" : "OK"
                }
            },
            "item3.1.2": {
                "attr1": [],
                "attr2": "",
                "attr3": [],
                "status" : "ERROR"
            }
        }
    }

};


const makeFlat = (obj, flatObj = {}) => {
    Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        if (!value || typeof value !== 'object')
            return;
        if (Object.keys(value).includes("status")) {
            flatObj[key] = value;
        } else {
            makeFlat(value, flatObj);
        }
    });
    return flatObj;
}

const filterByStatus = (obj, status) => {
    const result = {};
    Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        if(value.status === status) {
            result[key] = value;
        }
    });
    return result;
}

const flatObject = makeFlat(data);
console.log(flatObject);
const filteredFlatObject = filterByStatus(flatObject, "ERROR");
console.log(filteredFlatObject);
```

Answer (score 1):

I keep handy various useful functions.  One of them is [`pathEntries`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a1243641%20pathEntries), which works something like `Object .entries`, but instead of returning just the root values, keeps the entire paths to all nodes.  For instance, one of them might be

```js
  [["item2", "item2.1", "item2.1.1", "item2.1.1.1", "status"], "WARNING"]
```

and another one:

```js
  [["item2", "item2.1", "item2.1.1"], {
     "item2.1.1.1": {attr1: [], attr2: "", attr3: [], status: "WARNING"}
  }]
```

Using this, we can easily get all of these entries, filter to include only those with the proper `status` node, then trim the paths to include only the last node, then rehydrate an object with these values

```js
const deepObjFilter = (pred) => (o) => Object .fromEntries (
  pathEntries (o) .filter (([p, v]) => pred (v)) .map (([p, v]) => [p .at (-1), v])
)

const pathEntries = (o, p = []) => [
  ... (p .length > 0 ? [[p, o]] : []),
  ... (Object (o) === o ? Object .entries (o) .flatMap (
        ([k, v]) => pathEntries (v, [...p, Array .isArray (o) ? Number (k) : k])) : []
      )
]

const data = {item1: {"item1.1": {"item1.1.1": {"item1.1.1.1": {attr1: [], attr2: "", attr3: [], status: "ERROR"}}}, "item1.2": {"item1.2.1": {"item1.2.1.1": {attr1: [], attr2: "", attr3: [], status: "WARNING"}}}}, item2: {"item2.1": {"item2.1.1": {"item2.1.1.1": {attr1: [], attr2: "", attr3: [], status: "WARNING"}}, "item2.1.2": {"item2.1.2.1": {attr1: [], attr2: "", attr3: [], status: "OK"}, "item2.1.2.2": {attr1: [], attr2: "", attr3: [], status: "WARNING"}}}}, item3: {"item3.1": {"item3.1.1": {"item3.1.1.1": {attr1: [], attr2: "", attr3: [], status: "OK"}}, "item3.1.2": {attr1: [], attr2: "", attr3: [], status: "ERROR"}}}}

console .log (deepObjFilter (o => o .status === 'ERROR') (data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

And of course we can also preconfigure the search like this:

```js
const filterByStatus = (status) => deepObjFilter (o => o .status === status)
// later
filterByStatus ('ERROR') (data)
```

or even

```js
const getErrors = filterByStatus ('ERROR')
// later
getErrors (data)
```

---

The important point here is that having useful utility functions around can make such problems quite simple.